# Preserving columns when converting PDF to Excel Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, adobe-acrobat, spreadsheet

I have a PDF of data which I receive on a monthly basis. The PDF is about 100 pages. The problem is when I convert the PDF to Excel, I lose the formatting of the columns and the data becomes too messy to parse through. For example, sometimes several columns will appear in one cell, etc. I have tried using the Text to Columns function to fix those cases, but this also doesn't work because it doesn't align with the column headers. In addition, the process is quite tedious if I have to do this, and the idea is to make this process as automated as possible. I also would like to not have to download any additional software, as I am not sure my company would pay for this.

Comment: How are you doing the conversion?

Comment: @harrymc I just saved the PDF as an Excel Spreadsheet within Adobe Reader. I also tried copy/pasting the data, as well as converting to word first.

Comment: That does nothing except create a spreadsheet with the text in the first column. Not very useful. Better post a small example PDF if you want us to have a look.

Comment: Are you generating the PDF or is it being generated for you?

Comment: yep, pdf format is not so good when trying to pull data from it. Really best thing is to  get your data directly in excel format. If not you really are looking at writing custom VBA script.

Comment: @Wutnaut it's being generated for me

Comment: Like @gns100 is saying, you should contact the generator of the PDF and request it as an Excel spreadsheet instead.

Comment: tried smallpdf.com?